# The past perfect event happens before which sentence? The next one or the previous one?

Tags: meaning-in-context, past-tense, past-perfect, grammaticality-in-context, past-simple

If there is no such word as *before* or *when*, how do I know when the past perfect event takes place? I tried to figure out the context, but which is the context, the previous sentence or the next sentence?
For example:

> The Emperor straightened up and reflected.
> Wellington had fallen back.
> It only remained to complete this repulse with a crushing charge.
> Napoleon, turning abruptly, sent off a courier at full speed to Paris to announce that the battle was won.
> Napoleon was one of those geniuses from who give off thunder.
> **He had found his thunderbolt.**
> He ordered Milhaud’s cuirassiers to take the plateau of Mont-Saint-Jean.

When does the event *He had found his thunderbolt* take place? Which event does it happen before? The next sentence *He ordered Milhaud’s cuirassiers to...* or the previous sentence *Napoleon turning abruptly, sent off...*?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Presumably *you* wrote this text (it contains many things that no native speaker would ever write), so surely you know what you meant.

Comment: (Also, I suspect that "finding one's clap of thunder" may be a meaningful idiomatic usage in *your* native language; it's not idiomatic in English.)

Comment: Presumably, he had an idea while thinking about the military situation, which made him 'turn round abruptly' etc. etc.

Comment: It is actually from a English translation of Victor Hugo’s Novel Les Miserables. That “clap of thunder” means thunderbolt. I’m going to use a clearer version because this one is probably too old.

Comment: Your recent edit introduced a few errors; I suggest not changing the original.

Comment: You should indicate in your question where the text came from, so that it's clear it's a translation. It will help people write better answers.

Comment: It's hysterical!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the text in question is almost unintelligible.

Comment: It seems the OP modified or mistranscribed [the original text from *Les Miserables* by Victor Hugo](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Pictures_from_English_History/-JQQAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Napoleon+was+one+of+those+geniuses+from+who+give+off+thunder&pg=PA258&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: When an OP attempts to simplify a piece of literature and obviously does a poor job at it, can users please rollback the edit? The original made much more sense and as I found out, is from “Les Miserables”. This is why ATTRIBUTION and correct CITATIONS are important.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that "finding his thunderbolt" refers to Napoleon's idea to "complete this repulse with a crushing charge." This is how I understood the segment: Napoleon has the idea to send a cavalry charge, and sends word to Paris that he has won before the battle is even finished. This charge is a bold and cocky move, which the author describes metaphorically as a "thunderbolt". Then, the next sentence describes Napoleon putting his plan into action, by sending Milhaud's cuirassiers to take the plateau.

Books in English are usually written in the past tense, so when a sentence is in the past perfect, it is referring to something which happened **before** the current frame of reference of the book. This sentence cannot refer to the previous sentence, where Napoleon sends word to Paris, because Napoleon does not "find" or discover anything in this sentence. So, Napoleon having his idea to send a cavalry charge (two sentences earlier) must be the moment where he "finds his thunderbolt". Interpreting this segment correctly requires many context clues, and is not particularly easy even for a native English speaker.

Keep in mind that using "thunderbolt" in this manner (as to mean "a bold show of force") is not at all typical in English. I am not sure whether this is a French idiom or simply an unclear metaphor which was clearer in French. However, once I picked up on the metaphor, this segment became much easier to analyze.